# How can run 2 separate regression models with lmer using only one formula?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lme4, mixed-models

Consider, "y" as the dependent variable and "x1" and "x2" as the independent variables.
Consider two categorical variables "GROUPING" and "REGION" with 2 levels each.
Consider data_model with all the variables.

Consider 2 lmer models,

```
data_model_R1 = subset(data_model, REGION=='R1')
formula_R1 = "y ~ 1 + x1 + x2 + (1 + x1 | GROUPING) + (1 + x2 | GROUPING)"
model_R1 = lmer(formula_R1 , data_model_R1)

data_model_R2 = subset(data_model, REGION=='R2')
formula_R2 = "y ~ 1 + x1 + x2 + (1 + x1 | GROUPING) + (1 + x2 | GROUPING)"
model_R2 = lmer(formula_R2 , data_model_R2)
```

How can I create an equivalent "model" with one formula to get all the coefficients generated in "model_R1" and "model_R2"?
Something like,

```
model = lmer(formula, data_model)
```

Comment: can you post the data

Answer (score 0):

> How can I create an equivalent "model" with one formula to get all the coefficients generated in "model_R1" and "model_R2"

You can't really do exactly that. You are splitting the data for each model according to the values of the `REGION` variable. People typically do this when they expect associations between the predictors and the response to vary, depending on the value of another variable (`REGION` in this case). However, this is usually a bad idea because it leads to a big loss in statistical power. Instead, a better idea is to fit the interaction between the other variable and whichever variable(s) are expected to have a different association with the response. For example, if we wanted to allow the assocation between `x2` and `y` to vary depending on the value of `REGION` we would fit:

```
y ~ 1 + x1 + x2*REGION + (1 + x1 | GROUPING) + (1 + x2 | GROUPING)
```